# android_tutorial_camera

Tags: ros-hydro, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a project I have to connect an Arduino to a pc via a Android Phone using ROS. I installed ROS hydro on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine along with the rosjava and ros android packages. For these installations I used the tutorials on the ROS wiki.

After the installation I wanted to test the connection between the Android Phone and the pc which runs a roscore. To do this I used the android_tutorial_camera which I installed on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with stock Android 4.3 on it. Unfortunately, the phone does not connect to the roscore on the pc. When I use rosnode list I only see the nodes that are running on the pc.

When I ran the app with adb logcat enabled I noticed that in the stacktrace there is an IP-address which is not correct and which I did not gave as input when the app asked for an IP. Could anyone explain why the app uses another IP adress than the IP address that is given as input to the app ? And how can I solve this problem?

Some remarks on the setup/things that I already tried:

- The pc can ping the phone and the phone can ping the pc.
- The network used is the eduroam wifi network of the TU Delft.
- I entered the IP both manually and via a QR code into the app.
- I did change the ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI of the roscore on the pc.
- I use the fat workspace as described in the android tutorial.

Unfortunately I couldn't post the stacktrace here, because it was full of links and I don't have enough karma yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187440/android_tutorial_camera/) by [WFH27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19818/wfh27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This turned out to be a firewall issue, between the wireless and wired networks.

Nothing wrong with the ros android nodes or the master.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0